# Finding surface integral. Alternative parametric equation of sphere?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Evaluate the integral for the given data. Describe the kind of surface. Show the details of your work.

The vector field $\vec{F} = [0,x,0]$ and the surface $S$ is given by $S:x^{2}+ y^{2}+ z^{2}=1$ where $x \geq 0, y \geq 0, z \geq 0$

So S appears to be a sphere. I keep finding that the parametric equation of a sphere is:

$$ x = r cos(v) cos(u), y = r cos(v) sin(u), z = r sin(v)$$

or

$$x = r cos(v)sin(u), y = r sin(v), sin(u), z = r cos(u)$$

Why the different equations? Why is v first?

Anyway, I'll take the first one. So::

$$r(u,v) = [ \cos{v} \cos{u}, \cos{v} \sin{u}, \sin{v} ]$$

$$F[r(u,v)) = [ 0 , \cos{v} \cos{u}, 0 ]$$
$$r_u = [ -cos v sin u , \cos{v} \cos{y}, 0 ]$$
$$r_v = [ -sin v cos u , -\sin{v} \sin{u}, cos v ]$$

Is that right so far?

My main question is the parametric representation of a sphere. Why the two equations online? How are they derived? Why does v come first?

Comment: To be clear, you don't *need* a parametrization like these involving angles to solve the original problem about flux through an eighth of a sphere.

Answer (score 1):

Let's use $\theta$ and $\varphi$, where $0\leq \theta\leq 2\pi$ describes the angle on the $xy$ plane and $0\leq \varphi\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$ describes the angle with the positive $z$ axis. Denote a sphere to have magnitude $\rho$.

Obviously, in polar coordinates, $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$. In the standard picture in spherical coordinates, one can look at the right triangle with hypothenuse $\rho$ and acute angle $\varphi$ and conclude that $z=\rho\cos\varphi$ and $r=\rho\sin\varphi$. Plugging in, we have $x=\rho \sin\varphi\cos\theta,$ $y=\rho\sin\varphi\sin\theta.$

In your problem, we are just replacing $\theta$ and $\varphi$ with $u$ and $v$.

Comment: if $\varphi$ = 0, doesn't that mean r = 0? When would the radius be 0?

Comment: @Jwan622 Yes, $\varphi=0$ makes $r=0$ (but not $\rho=0$) by $r=\rho\sin\varphi$.

Comment: I just visually don't understand thte right triangle... in a sphere when would r = 0? shouldn't the radius here always be constant?